# how to hide and show componet in react js using a single button

Tags: reactjs

I am still trying out React JS. So, I want to be able to hide and show componet in react js using a single button. I have tried my best and watched videos. I can do this if I wanted to use two different buttons, but I want to use same button. Just one button to either hide or show the component. So far, when I click on the button, it shows the component, but when I click on it again to hide the same component, I can't seem to get it to work.

So, "Addbirth" is the name of the component that I imported and that is the component that I want to display when I click on a button "ADD BITHDAY" and hide when I click on the same button.

Here is my code so far:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import "./home.css";
import {dataFile} from "./data";
import Addbirth from "../components/addbirthday"

export default function Home() {
const [showAdd, setShowAdd] = useState([]);

const showRemove = () =>{
if(showAdd){
  setShowAdd(Addbirth)
 }
 else if(!setShowAdd){
  setShowAdd([])
 }

}

 return (
    
    <>
    
   {showAdd }
    
    <div className="container homeContainer">
        
       <div className="homeWrapper">
           <div className="addContainer">
                <h2 className="headerTitle">You have 5 birthdays today</h2>
                <button className="btn" onClick={ showRemove} >ADD BITHDAY</button>
           </div>
```

Thank you as you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import "./home.css";
import {dataFile} from "./data";
import Addbirth from "../components/addbirthday"

export default function Home() {
const [isAddShow, setAddShow] = useState(false);

const handleClick = () =>{
setAddShow(!isAddShow)
 }

}

 return (
    
    <>
    
   {showAdd && <Addbirth />}
    
    <div className="container homeContainer">
        
       <div className="homeWrapper">
           <div className="addContainer">
                <h2 className="headerTitle">You have 5 birthdays today</h2>
                <button className="btn" onClick={ handleClick} >ADD BITHDAY</button>
           </div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT:
So at the beginning, you did:

```
const [showAdd, setShowAdd] = useState([]);
```

which means that showAdd will be an empty array [] because u pass that as initial state. That's okay, but later in code you did:

```
{showAdd }
```

this will always render showAdd value in the Home component even when it's an empty array, and that's not a good approach.

When you want to show components only on some condition best way is to use the ternary operator for example:

```
{isClicked ? <ComponentA/> : <ComponentB/>}
```

If isClicked is true ComponentA will be returned (rendered) when isClicked is false ComponentB will be returned, if you want to render something only on true you can do this:

```
{isClicked && <ComponentA/>}
```

Here you can read more about ternary: [MDN Ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

So you don't have to create an array for rendering components. I see you have a data file, if you want to render the same component multiple times for each let's say user or whatever you can do that like this:

```
dataFile.map(user => <UserComponent/>)
```

Keep in mind that in this case, dataFile must be an array.

I hope that it helped you to understand better now :)

Comment: This works. Thank you very much. I am trying to understand what is going on there. Do you mind explaining to me, please. Thanks. I understand the code. Yea, but I am trying to understand why it is working.

Comment: Just added an explanation in Edit, hope it helps.